# IOS Searchbar returns wrong data

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, searchbar

I am going crazy trying to get my IOS Searchbar working for the Iphone.  I access data from a remote server and populate a content file.  I then do a filter which creates a filtered content file.  I then do a [self.tableView reloadData()].  It works fine the first time around.  Then I change my scope and do another fetch of data from my server and filter it and do another reload.  However, the second time the table shows the first 9 items from the previous display rather than the new 9 items from the filtered file.  I console display the file count in the filtered file which in this case is 9 in the tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  I also display each item going through the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  In the cellForRowAtIndexPath I am displaying the correct 9 unfiltered items but they do not show up on the table!  The table shows the first 9 items from the old display instead.

My question is doesn't the new data display on the table instead of the old data even though the count is correct?  Why am I displaying the correct items on the console but yet the display shows items from the old display. WHat do I need to do to make the new data appear? I know this is pretty hard to comprehend but I am listing some of my code below in hopes that someone can give me a clue on why the table view is not being updated with the latest data.

```
     //  This is where I get data back from the server.

     self.listContent = [[NSArray alloc] init];

     if(_scopeIndex == 0)
         self.listContent = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"burials"];
     else
         if(_scopeIndex == 1)
             self.listContent = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"obits"];
         else
             self.listContent = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"photos"];

     if(self.listContent > 0)
     {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
          [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
     }
```

Below is where the data is filtered.  In this case the unfiltered and filtered file are the same.

```
        - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
/*
 Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
 */

[self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];// First clear the filtered array.

/*
 Search the listContent for names that match and add to the filtered array.
 */

for (int i = 0; i < [self.listContent count]; i++)
{

        NSComparisonResult result = [self.listContent[i][@"LastName"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:self.listContent[i]];
        }
//  }
}
```

}

This is where I get the table count of filtered items.

```
       - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    NSLog(@"Filtered Name count = %i", [self.listContent count]);
    return [self.filteredListContent count];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Name count = %i", [self.listContent count]);
    return [self.listContent count];
}
```

}

ANd this is where I update the cells in my table:

```
       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
if (cell == nil)
{

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}   

if(indexPath.row > [self.filteredListContent count] - 1)
    return cell;

 NSDictionary *burial = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *lastname = burial[@"LastName"];
NSString *firstname = burial[@"FirstName"];

NSString *burialname = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, %@", lastname, firstname];
 cell.textLabel.text = burialname;


NSLog(@"Cell name= %@ index path=%i", cell.textLabel.text, indexPath.row);
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I changed my logic to go to the server one time to get my content and this time included scope indicators in my content table.  This enables me to process scope filters without having to go back to the server for data for a specific scope.  Doing this resulted in proper view tables being displayed when changing scope.  I would not recommend going to the server ascynchronously  whenever the scope changes on the search as it really screws up the view table.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using searchbar? Logic should be that you have tableview with all data and the you use search bar to filter out matching results and add them to search data array and while searchbar is active you display search data array.

Is

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

used somewhere?

Added following

If you have this function set up you can update search array and reload it using something like

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView != nil)
{
    //Updates searchData array
    [self searchDisplayController:self.searchDisplayController shouldReloadTableForSearchString:searchBar1.text];

    //Updates display
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

}
else
{
    [_channelsTableView reloadData];
}
```

It is calling searchDisplayController with current search bar text. When new tableview data comes from server you can activate searchDisplayController to refresh search results array and then it is possible to refresh the display.

Comment: I do have the shouldReloadTableForSearchString function.  That is where I call the function to create the filtered array to display and return YES.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

1. Maybe you're reloading your tableView too soon, or
2. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs to distinguish between the table views (just as your `numberOfRowsInSection` does), or
3. Maybe you don't have all of your delegates set up correctly.  The searchBar is used with a `UISearchDisplayController`, which has 2 delegates: `searchResultsDataSource` and `searchResultsDelegate`.  Make sure those are set to self (or whatever class handles these).

Comment: I have the following delegates set:  [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
 [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
    [searchDisplayController searchResultsDelegate:self];  However when I try to add [searchDisplayController searchResultsDelegate:self]; I get the error  'No visible @interface for 'UISearchDisplay COntroller' declares the selector 'search ResultsDelegate'.

Comment: @Dave there are two flavors of syntax you can use  `[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self]`   or `searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;`  I think you left out the 'set' in your statement.

Comment: I changed it to use setSearchResultsDelegate:self but it didn't make any difference in the results.  I am console displaying the correct entries in cellForRowAtIndexPath function but they are not displayed on the view.  It displays the correct number of entries but it list the first 9 old entries.  It is really confusing.

Comment: This is my delegate list in my .h file.  @interface CEMSearchViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: I think part of the problem is that I am getting data asynchronously from the server and the view diplay is one step behind the results from the server.  It is preferable to do synchronous fetch from the server?

Comment: Whenever the scope changes on my search bar I go to the server to get new data.  This is proving impossible to work with in the IOS search logic as the number of rows and data return are never in sync.  Therefore, I am changing my logic to get all possible scopes of data and examine the original data each time the scope changes rather than going back to the server to get data based on the scope.

Comment: "In this case the unfiltered and filtered file are the same" - I think you need to keep 2 distinct arrays of data - filtered, and unfiltered.  And every method that takes a tableView as a parameter needs to ask: is this filtered or unfiltered, and then get it's data from the appropriate list.  cellForRowAtIndexPath, numnberOfRowsInSection are the key ones.